# array loop but not displaying values

Tags: php, arrays, rest, api, woocommerce

My array is not displaying values

My code

```
 <?php 
 $line_items= array();
 $line_items=$_GET['line_items'];
 foreach ( $line_items as  $line_item ) {
 $line_item = [
        'quantity' => $line_item['quantity'],     
        'price'=>$line_item['price'],       
 ];
$order_data['line_items'][] = $line_item; 
 }
print_r($order_data);
 ?>
```

My output with this code

```
Array
(
[line_items] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [quantity] =>
                [price] => 
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [quantity] =>
                [price] => 
            )

    )

 )
```

Error ? Array is not displaying value from this parameter 
xy.php?line_items[quantity][]=2&line_items[quantity][]=4&line_items[price][]=4&line_items[price][]=8

expected output

```
 Array
 (
   [line_items] => Array
   (
       [0] => Array
          (
            [quantity] => 2          
            [price] => 4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [quantity] => 4               
            [price] => 8
        )

  )
 )
```

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks

Comment: The correct one should be: `xy.php?line_items[0][quantity]=2&line_items[1][quantity]=4&line_items[0][price]=4&line_items[1][price]=8`

Comment: It works but instead of line_items[0][quantity] line_items[1] quantity etc, you know how to make it dynamic without manually assigning 0,1 etc . changes in the code would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It depends on how you are doing in your HTML code. If possible edit your question and add your HTML.

Comment: Well its actually for api for android app not html and I test using postman before using on my android code.

Comment: @Valdeir Psr it works thanks for your valuable answer I managed to loop line_items[0][quanity]=value1;line_items[1][quanity]=value2; using for loop as line_items[i][quanity]=value ith time. Thank you million times much appreciated. I could select as best answer but can't coz your answer is a comment.